# How to use Google Sign In with android

Tags: android, post, google-signin

In my app I've implemented a Google Sign-In Button as the main activity. So the user logs in, fills out a survey, and when they hit send, I need it to send a POST to the google form I've setup. How can I get the user's login(from the main activity) and send it to the website to allow access to the form itself?

The form is setup so that you need to be logged in through google to get to the form. I've been reading something about tokens but am not sure how to send this token to the login page of google.

Comment: Have you tried passing `GoogleSignInAccount` variable? I've had a brief look over the documentation and that's what I'd try first: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in#start_the_sign-in_flow

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I'm trying to do but my knowledge on http requests is rather limited. I'm not sure how to access the text boxes on the page and how to input the email/password from the GoogleSignInAccount variable, but I'll keep trying!